# Package Laravel Application Into Docker Image

Tags: laravel, docker, ibm-cloud, docker-image

I have created a Laravel 5.2 application and I want to create it's docker image but I am new to Docker. Can someone guide me through the process or help me with web links where I could get information on building Laravel docker images.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Googling this process at all? I would suggest you start there, and if you get stuck then come back with where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this docker image, image: woohuiren/php-laravel-env:latest
https://hub.docker.com/r/woohuiren/php-laravel-env/~/dockerfile/

Comment: Thanks for your comment Vineesh. I think I am totally missing the concept of using Docker. Laravel environment goes to the docker container over server then how do we edit code and attach a MySQL database. Sorry if it sounds stupid.